# Deprecated method to read content message on swift3

Tags: swift3, deprecated, mailcore2

What i can use to replace this method in swift 3 - mailcore2 to read content of messege? I have warning that this is deprecated.

```
 let fetchContentoperation: MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation = imapsession.fetchMessageByUIDOperation(withFolder: folder, uid: number_message)
```

I use this but i woud like to use not deprecated method. Is exist any another method to read mail content if i use mailcore2-ios

Comment: replace it by `fetchMessageOperationWithFolder`

Comment: hello i am facing the same issue, did you find the solution?